# Как привести эту строку в "нормальную" кодировку?

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
&#x414;&#x435;&#x439;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x438;&#x442;&#x435;&#x43B;&#x44C;&#x43D;&#x44B;&#x439;
```

Пример: Действительный <- (посмотрите исходный код этого слова)

Если вывести ее в на страницу - то отображает русское слово. Как сделать чтобы и в исходном коде было тоже русское слово?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дак и замените ее в исходном коде, или о чем вопрос то?

Comment: @teran приведенная строка в браузере (на странице) отображается нормально, как русский текст. но если например делать php скрипт и записывать эту строку в ексель файл, или в базу mysql, да куда угодно - тогда мы видим эту строку символами #&x11. то есть прочитать ее можно только браузером сейчас(

Comment: ну дак найдите эту строку в пхп коде и замените на обычный текст, или о чем речь? вы эту строку откуда то получаете извне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это побуквенные коды UTF8 - переписать в базе. А вообще, нужно настраивать конвертацию при записи в базу и/или извлечении из нее. Да, и посмотрите кодировки в htaccess и самого файла - на всякий случай.

Конвертор, может пригодится http://pressdev.ru/perevodim-kirillicu-v-utf-8-na-veb-sajte/?aid=1531&sa=0

Comment: а как мне на php привести эту строку в человеческий вид?

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад! А решение Ваше - так что тоже +)